# Использование одного массива в нескольких событиях

Tags: c#, массивы

День добрый, имеется у меня несколько событий Button_Click, выполняющих определенные действия с массивыми.
Вопрос заключается вот в чем - как распространить массив, заполненный случайными значениями на все события с одними и теми же значениями.

В коде, используются два массива, но они будут генерировать разные значения. Нужно, чтобы они были одинаковые во всех последующих генерациях.

```
public class Form1
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // Это генерация массива 
    {
        int [] a = new int [n];
        dataGridView1.ColumnCount = n;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            a[i] = rn.Next(1, 30);
            dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[i].Value = a[i];
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // Это выполняет действие по смене элементов
    {
        int [] a = new int [n];
        dataGridView1.ColumnCount = n;
        int k = Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text),
            m = Convert.ToInt32(textBox4.Text);
        int C = a[k];
        a[k] = a[n];
        a[n] = C;
        for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
        {
            a[i] = rn.Next(1, 30);
            dataGridView2.Rows[0].Cells[i].Value = a[i];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Дайте код.

Comment: Изменил, добавил код.

Comment: Сделайте массив не локальным, а полем класса (формы).

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov каким образом его заполнить случайными числами и распространить на все последующие его инициализации с такими же значениями?

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так

```
public class Form1
{
    private int[] a;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            a[i] = rn.Next(1, 30);            
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // Это генерация массива 
    {       
        dataGridView1.ColumnCount = n;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {            
            dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[i].Value = a[i];
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // Это выполняет действие по смене элементов
    {        
        dataGridView1.ColumnCount = n;
        int k = Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text),
            m = Convert.ToInt32(textBox4.Text);
        int C = a[k];        
        for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
        {            
            dataGridView2.Rows[0].Cells[i].Value = a[i];
        }
    }
```